# Double parenthesis confusion (Discrete Mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

1-    ((¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∨ R) ∨ (Q ∨ R))**∨ R**

2-   (¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∨ R) ∨ (Q ∨ R)**∨ R**

3-  (¬P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∨ R) ∨ **(Q ∨ R) ∨ (R ∨ R)**

Q:Why did we remove the double parenthesis after step number 1?

Also, my thinking process was that I could distribute the R outside the double parenthesis over the sub-groups inside the double parenthesis (Distribute it over the whole thing) and not only distribute the R outside the double parenthesis over (Q ∨ R) only.

*Note: I am new to Discrete-Mathematics and to this site. I would very appreciate some  tips on what to improve and learn, but be gentle with me since I am like still a newbie.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Because "and" is associative, like $+$: $(1+1)+1=1+1+1$.

Comment: Mauro thank you! It might be just that.

Comment: You can't and should not have removed the parenthis without distributing the the NOT first.

Comment: "I could distribute the R outside the double parenthesis over the sub-groups inside the double parenthesis"  You have to deal with the NOT first.  But then, yes, you could distribute through the d0ulbe paren.  (Which would no longer be ANDS because we had distrubed the NOT).  Where are these statements from.  It seems to me they are all wrong.

Comment: Oh.... here it is @MauroALLEGRANZA comment that OR is associative that we can get rid of the double paren.  We *could* distribute then OR $R$ over the minor grouping but there is no need. Im not sure why the third step was done.  As AND is associative I'd have just written $(\lnot P\land V)\lor P\lor R\lor Q\lor R\lor R$ and as OR is absorbtive ($A\lor A = A$) and commutative I'd get $(\lnot P\land V)\lor P\lor Q\lor R$

Comment: @fleablood, the 3rd step was just so that I could emphasis on the step where we distributed R over a sub-group (Q ∨ R)  instead of just distributing the R over the whole double parenthesis (which is not possible because there is no "AND" inside ). Which brings us to the step that is appropriate for this predicament, and that is the "Associative law".

Answer (score 0):

Something isn't right:

1 $\neg ((\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (P \lor R) \lor (Q \lor R)) \lor R$

is **not** equivalent to

2 $\neg (\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (P \lor R) \lor (Q \lor R) \lor R$

Rather, it is equivalent to:

2 $(\neg (\neg P \land \neg Q) \land \neg (P \lor R) \land \neg (Q \lor R)) \lor R$

And notice that with that, you can *not* drop parentheses.

Comment: The thing is I haven't even tried to learn formatting my questions so my bad.
Can you look at it again?

Comment: @ExperimentalUnit Ah! Ok, that makes more sense. And it’s just Associativity. It’s just like addition: it doesn’t matter in what order you add things together: $2+(3+7) = (2+3)+7$, which is why we just write $2+3+7$. Same with a bunch of $\lor$’s

Comment: Thank you very much!